# How to Avoid Nested Ifs for Debugging

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested, nested-if

I have a JS script that checks whether a 3-condition requirement is met, in this format:

```
if (A)
   if (B)
      if (C)
         debug("Requirement met!")
      else debug("C not met")
   else debug("B not met")
else debug("A not met)
```

It works, but it's quite lengthy, especially when that requirement instead has 10 different conditions and I need to know **which condition** was not met. Is there a cleaner, more readable way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is rather psuedocode-y and speculative, but why not put the conditions in an array and loop over them? `for (const [msg, cond] of [["blah", someBoolean], ...]) { if (!cond) { debug(msg); break; }};`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```js
if (!A)      debug("A not met")
else if (!B) debug("B not met")
else if (!C) debug("C not met")
else         debug("Requirement met!")
```